# Can we expose Microsoft Purview home/search page without granting IAM access to the users requesting it?

Tags: azure-purview

Is it necessary to assign "Data Readers" access to enable people to access Purview?

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/catalog-permissions

Yes, assigning roles on the collections is the only way to grant permissions.